# .GetElementsByName.SelectedIndex visibly changes option but not programmatically?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, web-scraping, queryselector

I am having an issue and do not know how to resolve it, In Excel VBA I have this code that takes me through a website (https://indexcalculator.ftserussell.com/), however on step 3 of the site when I change the selected indices via vba I can see that they get changed on the webpage but when the next page button is clicked it is as if it were never clicked.

Selected Indices Changing:

[image]

After Get Returns Clicked:

[image]

```
    months = Format(DateSerial(year(Date), month(Date) - 1, 1), "m")
    days = Format(DateSerial(year(Date), month(Date), 0), "d")
    years = CInt(Format(DateSerial(year(Date), month(Date) - 1, 1), "yyyy")) - 1994

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    'If the year pops up blank that means that the base year is no longer 1994
    HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("m_startDate")(0).selectedIndex = CInt(months - 1)
    HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("d_startDate")(0).selectedIndex = CInt(days - 1)
    HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("y_startDate")(0).selectedIndex = years
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    Set oButton = HTMLdoc.querySelector("a[href='javascript:submitForm(document.forms[0].action);']")
    oButton.Click

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    Set oButton = HTMLdoc.querySelector("a[href='javascript:document.forms[0].target='_blank';submitForm('IndexDownload.aspx');']")
    oButton.Click
```

The Step 4 page should have said May 31st not June 13, When I do it manually it works. Why does this happen?

Comment: **Wow** it's unsettling (or something) to see DOM operations in VBA. :-) I immediately thought "Wait a minute, `HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("m_startDate")(0).selectedIndex =` can't work!" But it can, because this is VBA, not JavaScript. :-D

Comment: you probably need to manually fire the change() event on the select, simply setting the index doesn't fire it, and it sounds like functionality depends on it firing, which happens when an actual user changes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work fine. Adjust css selectors to the values you want to select for end dates. In particular look at css [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selectors which I use heavily below.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim ie As Object, days As Long, months As Long, years As Long
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://indexcalculator.ftserussell.com/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        months = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1), "m")
        days = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0), "d")
        years = 1994


        With .document
            .querySelector("[value='irs3']").Click 'step 1
            .querySelector("#Ctlnavigation2_lblControl [href*=action]").Click

            While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            .querySelector("#rdoSpDtRng").Click 'step 2
            .querySelector("#Ctlnavigation2_lblControl [href*=action]").Click

            While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            .querySelector("[value='" & months & "']").Selected = True 'step 3
            .querySelector("[value='" & days & "']").Selected = True
            .querySelector("[value='" & years & "']").Selected = True
            .querySelector("[name='m_endDate'] [value='" & months + 1 & "']").Selected = True
            .querySelector("[name='d_endDate'] [value='" & days - 1 & "']").Selected = True
            .querySelector("[name='y_endDate'] [value='" & years + 1 & "']").Selected = True
            .querySelector("#Ctlnavigation2_lblControl [href*=action]").Click
            While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        End With
        Stop                                     '<delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You I will give this a try later today or Monday!

Comment: Pleasure. Check my answer to your prior question as I'm not sure the accepted answer will work throughout your program - I'm guessing you want to click through each next.